# UIView Content Clipping Not Working/UIView Resize Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, resize

I ran into an issue where clipping of subviews is not working consistently (or potentially, the UIView resize isn't working). Here's the scenario:

- I have a UIView (section above the line). The actual size is larger to accommodate search bar. I basically resize it on viewDidLoad.
- When clicking on the text field, UIView expands and show a search bar
- After search, I collapse the UIView, but found that the UIView is not collapsed in certain case (see first image). If I were to not hide the search bar, it will remain also.

Is there any reason why this issue occurs? I'm still trying to debug and see if there is anything that could have caused this issue (as something may reset to original size). It definitely does seem like everything is resized correctly since even the result table is moved correctly also. Something else must have triggered it after the expected resize. Any pointer is appreciated. I've only done iOS development for 5 days so I'm still not aware of a lot of things.

```
- (void)showAddressField
{
    CGRect headerFrame = self.searchHeaderView.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = headerHeight + adjustmentSize;
    self.searchHeaderView.frame = headerFrame;

    CGRect tableFrame = resultTableView.frame;
    tableFrame.size.height = tableHeight - adjustmentSize;
    tableFrame.origin.y = headerFrame.size.height + statusBarHeight;
    resultTableView.frame = tableFrame;

    [self renderHeaderBorder:headerFrame.size.height - 1];
}

- (void)hideAddressField
{    
   CGRect headerFrame = self.searchHeaderView.frame;
   headerFrame.size.height = headerHeight;
   self.searchHeaderView.frame = headerFrame;

   CGRect tableFrame = resultTableView.frame;
   tableFrame.size.height = tableHeight;
   tableFrame.origin.y = headerHeight + statusBarHeight;
   resultTableView.frame = tableFrame;

   [self renderHeaderBorder:headerHeight - 1];
```

}

### EDITED

SearchHeaderView is just a UIView that is a subview of the main view. It's not a table header. I found that if I put a search bar in the table header, it behaves very unpredictably so I have a UIView containing the search portion and have a UITableView right below it.

Sorry, since I only have just over a week to get a rather massive app out from scratch, I didn't have time to wait. I already changed my approach a little bit, but I will still award the points even after the bounty has expired. I'm trying to understand everything to do with layout since that's pretty much the only thing that I can't quite figure out with iOS app development.

[image: UIView Clip Subviews Issue]
[image: UIView expanded]

Comment: "Placing and moving your views can be a little tricky if you don’t know the details of UIView’s frame, bounds, and center properties.  This post gives a quick intro to those along with a useful category for working with them"  http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=24

Comment: @juminoz - Paste 3 snippets of code. 1) Code that initializes the UI View in first snapshot 2) Code that makes it bigger in second snapshot 3) Code that makes it smaller but actually does not work after search.. I will see if I can replicate the problem..

Comment: Could you please post more code so I can help you? what are searchHeaderView, headerHeight, statusBarHeight and renderHeaderBorder?

Comment: Is this UITableView header? if so then make sure you adjust the headerView height properly in heightForHeader delegate. If not then post more code or just tell what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the search bar is in the table view header, try reassigning the header view to the table view:

```
[tableView setTableHeaderView:self.searchHeaderView];
```

If it is a section header, be sure to update the value for the delegate's

```
– tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

Otherwise, please post more code on how the searchHeaderView is initialized and added to the table.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, frames are already relative to the enclosing window.  You should not be taking into account the height of the status bar (assuming that refers to the 20px area at the top of the screen).

I have found in the past that you may need to implement "layoutSubviews" in your view controller and compute the frames of the views there.  It depends on your resizing mask / if you auto-layout enabled.

As the others have stated, more code would be helpful... or at least the relevant portions of the nib/xib.